# Read something from a text file with fread and print it on screen in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I try to read a string from a text file and print it on screen, but I manage to print only the first character and I don't know how to fix it. I tried to change the format to `%s` but if I do that I get a blank screen. Thank you for help. Here's my code:

```
.data
tfile1 db "text.txt", 0
read   db "rb", 0
write  db "wb",0
format db "%c", 0
buffer db 0
.code
start:
push offset read          ;put read binary operation on stack
push offset tfile1        ;put text.txt on stack
call fopen                ;open text.txt
add ESP, 8                ;clear stack
mov esi, eax              ;save pointer to the stack
push esi                  ;stream
push 1                    ;count
push 1                    ;size
push offset buffer
read_loop:
call fread  
test eax,eax              ;check if eax=0
jz close_tfile
xor eax, eax              ;clear eax 
mov al, buffer            ; copy buffer in al
push eax                  ; put eax on stack
push offset format        ; put format on stack
call printf               ; print from text.txt
add esp, 8                ;clear stack
jmp read_loop
close_tfile:
add esp, 16               ; clear stack from fread
push esi                  ;stream   
call fclose
add esp,4 
push 0
call exit
end start
```

Comment: Your `read_loop` label should be before putting the arguments on the stack of course.

Comment: God !Thank you man ! I was stuck here for 1h ...